# Can I display Stored Procedure name on tabs

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

If I have stored procedures open then in the tabs it says "SQLQuery10.sql" etc

[image]

But if I open up some saved files the tabs are the titles of the files:

[image]

Is there a setting in the `IDE` to let me have the stored procedure names dipsplayed in the query tabs?

Comment: No this isn't possible without writing an addin to do it (or actually saving the contents as a file)

Comment: No, there is not. You can name your file the stored procedure.

Comment: Might be a good feature request to make to MS. I see value in not having a large number of tabs opened as SQLQuery1...200.

Comment: @MartinSmith how involved is writing an addin to do this? ....I often have many sprocs open simultaneously

Comment: @whytheq - Don't know really. I've only messed around with addins. There are some example projects on codeplex and from the guy behind SSMS boost that you can have a look at it. [Some links here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/25396/3690)

Comment: Some info from SSMSBoost guy: I have already investigated if it is possible to set tab titles without saving the document and found that it is not possible in without deep hacking. The possibility that exists is to add some "autosave" feature, that will simply autosave tab, as soon as you open source of some object. If you have a proposal and maybe your usage scenario you can post a proposal at ssmsboost forum (there is a "proposals" thread there). Maybe together we will find a good solutions.  I just need some more usage cases. (you can also use support@ssmsboost.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be hard for any IDE to do.  Consider these situations:

1. You are creating a new stored procedure, but you haven't put any code in it or tried to run the script yet.
2. You are modifying a stored procedure, but you change the name of the procedure.  Again, you haven't run the script yet.
3. Your file contains multiple stored procedures.  What should be in the table?
4. You are modifying a stored procedure, you change the name of the procedure, but there's a syntax error:  the code wouldn't be able to run.
5. You scripted a stored procedure change, then commented out everything in the file, including "ALTER PROCEDURE".

How should the IDE react to those situations?

The bottom line:  you're editing files, not stored procedure objects. In order to determine what stored procedure you're attempting to modify with your script, the IDE would have to read and parse your script, and make a lot of decisions about partial cases and unusual situations like those above.  It would be very difficult to please everybody, and inevitably someone would complain, "I'm saving it to a file!  Why can't it show me the file name in the tab!?"

Answer (score 3):

There is very helpful solution for auto renaming tabs in SSMS. Called "SSMS tool pack" it takes text in specified line as tab caption. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIp6r.png)

Comment: Thanks, this tool looks fantastic - just have to convince corporate IT to allow installation

Answer (score 2):

NO it is not possible, one of SSMS many failings IMHO